# If we are the bride, who are the invited?

Tags: exegesis, revelation, church-universal

Assuming that the Bride in the book of Revelation is talking about the church, then who are the invited in this verse?

> Then the angel said to me, “Write this: Blessed are those who are invited to the wedding supper of the Lamb!” And he added, “These are the true words of God.”

(Revelation 19:9)

If we are the Bride, I imagine we can't be the invited. If we are the invited, then we can't be the bride. Or do I misunderstand the language?

Answer (score 2):

Revelation 21:2 personified the New Jerusalem as a bride.

> 2 And I saw the holy city, New Jerusalem, coming down out of heaven from God, **prepared as a bride adorned for her husband.**

As we know through Scripture, New Jerusalem will be the city those in Christ will call home. With this description, the marriage would be between the Lord and the New Jerusalem, with the invited being us who are accepted in to the Holy City.

Comment: Now, what's the meaning of "God" marrying a city?

Comment: @User In order to understand that you must leave the Material realm and see it in the Spiritual realm. Marriage in the Kingdom of God is not the same as marriage in our world. There it means the melding of the two into one. Which is exemplified in Scripture, where the partners leave their parents and become one. In the Kingdom of God marriage is much more than the physical uniting it is the total absorption of the two into a singular. As the father and the son are one in spirit so will the saved be one in God, a common spirit.

Comment: But most interpreters, I thought, identified the new Jerusalem as being the church.

Answer (score 1):

Jesus told several parables about weddings and feasts, such as the parable of the ten bridesmaids/virgins. These parables are about the Jews who should have been prepared for Jesus' coming to earth, but instead refused him. So one common interpretation is that it will be the faithful Old Testament Jewish saints who will be the guests - those who had faith in God but who were not specifically part of the new covenant and not part of the church.

Depending on your eschatology there are other options as well. Some premillenialists teach that those saved during the millennium are a separate group from the church, and so would also be those invited to the wedding.

And it's pretty likely some angels will get an invite too!